# how to set data- value in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a script that uses the "data-" type to store info inside an html element.  E.G

```
<div class="My-Widget commentsandrating" data-XYZ="MCAN"></div>
<div class="My-Widget rating" data-XYZ="MCAN"></div>
<div class="My-Widget comments" data-XYZ="MCAN"></div>
```

some of these will be in the page with the data-XYZ and some as follows:

```
<div class="My-Widget commentsandrating"></div>
<div class="My-Widget rating"></div>
<div class="My-Widget comments"></div>
```

I am trying to add the data-xyz to the html.

For all browsers I use the following function

```
item.setAttribute('data-XYZ', queryString2);
```

and it works for every browser except for IE ..

I tried using jQuery

```
jQuery.data(item, 'XYZ', queryString2);
```

What should i use to set this instead..

Thanks for the help...

Comment: How you are getting your `item` variable?

Comment: when in doubt, try reading the jQuery API docs  http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: item is created using   $.each(widgetArray, function(index, item) widgetArray is created by a  results = document.querySelectorAll( '.' + sel ); which uses the pre-fix of the class name

Comment: I looked at the api docs see above post: jQuery.data(item, 'XYZ', queryString2);  was my understanding

Comment: @MB.   Admit it can be a bit confusing... there are 2 levels of `data` in API  `$.data` and `$.fn.data`. Link I  provided for `$.fn.data` is the one you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the answers are right, but I think they missed to explain what the code does.
In your case, you have two options:

1. Use `$('element').data('key', 'value')`. This will attach data to your DOM element. You can then retrieve it via `$('element').data('key')`
2. Add a custom attribute to your element with `$('element').attr('key','value')` and then retrieve it with `$('element').attr('key')`.

Although you're doing the same thing, both methods are different in how you achieve it.
For instance, using `data` gives you more choices - you can store whatever you want including JSON and Array data. With `$('element').attr('key','value')`, you can only store a string.

Depending on your choice:

```
(you choose to use data)
$('.commentsandrating').data('XYZ', 'MCAN');
var getData = $('.commentsandrating').data('XYZ'); // will return "MCAN"

(you choose to use attr)
$('.commentsandrating').attr('XYZ', 'MCAN');
var getData = $('.commentsandrating').attr('XYZ'); // will return "MCAN"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this. Might It Help You.

## HTML

```
<div class="My-Widget commentsandrating" data-XYZ="MCAN"></div>
<div class="My-Widget rating" data-XYZ="MCAN"></div>
<div class="My-Widget comments" data-XYZ="MCAN"></div>

<div class="My-Widget commentsandrating"></div>
<div class="My-Widget rating"></div>
<div class="My-Widget comments"></div>

<input type="button" id="set" value="set"/>
<input type="button" id="get" value="get"/>
```

## JS

```
$(function(){
  var queryString2 = "MCAN";
  var sel = "My-Widget";
  var widgetArray = document.querySelectorAll( '.' + sel );
  $('#set').on('click', function(){
      $.each(widgetArray, function(index, item){
         $.data(item, 'XYZ',  queryString2 + index);
      });
  });

  $('#get').on('click', function(){
      $.each(widgetArray, function(index, item){
         alert($.data(item, 'XYZ'));
      });
  });
});
```

CHECK This **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MKAmv/5/)**

Comment: Can't do that as I can have multiple items with the same class name i need to use the exact element from the array (see comment above) i have a var quertyString2 = further up the script

Comment: Wil try that I'll show answered if that works and upvote thanks

Comment: No joy:  this just does not change the html div

Comment: Hi I tried the JS fiddle It doesn't seem to do anything I tried changing sel = "My-Widget commentsandrating" and that doesn't fix it either

Comment: ok I oversimplified by question i guess I will change the question to show all variants

Comment: @MB check the updated answer and if you found some thing missing, please update in jsfiddle and provide the jsfiddle link

Comment: This works of a fashion but the best solution was using attr below  thankf for such great and speedy help

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".commentsandrating").attr("data-xyz") //to get value

$(".commentsandrating").attr("data-xyz", value) //to set value
```

Comment: used $(item).attr('data-xyz')